# selecting data from multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a basic question but I haven't been able to find answer. I am a little familiar with SQL and trying to write a search query to pull data from a match of two columns but I'm struggling to search for a term in two columns.

Imagine I have two columns - Ticker and Name. I want to search both and return matches if a match occurs in either one. For example, you can search IBM or International Business machine to get the same results.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT g.ticker, g.name 
FROM   "General" g 
WHERE  g.ticker ILIKE '%ibm%' 
LIMIT  25;
```

but I'm not sure how to incorporate g.name into it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
SELECT g.ticker, g.name 
FROM "General" g 
WHERE g.ticker ILIKE '%ibm%' OR g.name ILIKE '%ibm%'
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: that's simple, thank you. Is there any negative impact if both like are the same variable(%ibm%) in this case? I saw other examples where columns are concat'ed together, wasn't sure if it applied.

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . You can concatenate the values together, but that impedes the optimizer.  If you use named parameters, then this can just use a single parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I thought concatenation would be faster but you are saying the above way is faster. It's better for me as above is also very clean. Thank you.